# In Flutter, when I click on the TextFormField I get an overflowed error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                child: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.compass,
                  color: orange,
                  size: 26,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        Text(
          'The final step for exploration.',
          style: homepageSubtitle,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        TextFormWidget(
            onChanged: () => null,
            controller: _usernameController,
            labelText: 'Username',
            hintText: 'example@gmail.com'),
        TextFormWidget(
            onChanged: () => (value) => _checkPassword(value),
            controller: _passwordController,
            labelText: 'Password',
            hintText: 'Min. 8 characters'),
```

Here, I created the page you see in the image.

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20,
        vertical: 20,
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        onChanged: onChanged(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
          labelText: labelText,
          hintText: hintText,
          labelStyle: labelTextStyle,
          hintStyle: hintTextStyle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Here is the TextFormWidget I created.

[image]

If I click on a TextFormField to enter a value, I get an overflowed error. What should I wrap the widget I created or the place where I show this widget so that I don't get this error?

Answer (score 2):

Because keyboard appear make your Column doesn't has enough space. Try wrap your Column with SingleChildScrollView:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child : Column(
      children: [
        // your children
      ]
  );
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your `Scaffold`:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

When the keyboard opens you have less space on the screen, and now your `Column` doesn't fit in the space you have.

Simple solution is to wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView` which will make it scrollable and therefore remove overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've used sample code for the answer.

```
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 600,
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Bottom Overflow Error:**

[image]

### There are 3 ways to solve this issue:

##### 1. Adding resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false in Scaffold

If text fields are close to the bottom of the screen, this approach is not recommended because the keyboard can hide the text fields.

```
      Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Column( ...
```

**Output:**

[image]

##### 2. Wrap the Column widget within SingleChildScrollView

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column( ...
```

**Output:**

[image]

##### 3. By changing the Column widget to the ListView widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [ ...
```

**Output:**

[image]